# How can I map MS SQL datatype numeric(19, 0) to .NET type

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am working on the mapping from MS SQL database to POCO classes:

I have `numeric(19, 0)`, `numeric(18, 0)`, `numeric(3, 0)`, `numeric(3, 0)`.

I am using the EF power tools to generate **POCO** and all map to decimal `.NET` **C#** `Type`.

But I think it should map to `BigInt`, `Int64`, `Int32`, `Int16` etc.

Comment: What is the actual domain of your values? If it fits within a 2^63, you can use an `Int64`, for example.

Comment: I don't have any information about the domain values. I only got the MS SQL DB script.

Comment: How? Map it to a data type with at least the same capacity. EF Power Tools only generates a mapping for you to modify as you please.

Comment: Arnold: Yes, you are right. My first thought was not to update the EF Power Tools generated code in order to get the best performance. But then I found out the generated code has some issues and need to be updated a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the .NET integer types and their domains with maximum fitting numeric types:

- `SByte` => -128 to 127 which fits up to `NUMERIC(2, 0)`
- `Int16` => -32,768 to 32,767 which fits up to `NUMERIC(4, 0)`
- `Int32` => -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 which fits up to `NUMERIC(9, 0)`
- `Int64` => -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 which fits up to `NUMERIC(18, 0)`

Since a `decimal` can hold up to 7.9*10^28, it fits up to `NUMERIC(28, 0)`.

If you have an integer field bigger than `NUMERIC(28, 0)`, you can use `BigInteger` in .NET 4.0 or newer.

Answer (score 2):

`numeric(x, y)` will be decimal. If you want int the correct type is:

SQL / C#

- long     / Int64
- int      / Int32
- smallint / Int16

Comment: I don't have access to MS SQL side, so the MS SQL will always be numeric(19,0), numeric(18,0) and etc.